# How to add a Function inside a function

Tags: powershell

Im trying to add a function inside a function, So when someone types either 1,2 or 3 it will ask them to choose a directory (Documents, Downloads, Pictures) then it will go back to renaming, Creating or Deleting a Directory from that selected Directory.

So far the code works without the directory option but i seem to be having trouble incorporating it.
Here is the Code that i have Wrote.

```
cls

function create
{
    param(
    $name)

    $name = Read-Host "Which folder do you want to create?"
    New-Item $name -ItemType "directory"
    Write-Host "Folder" $name "is created"
}

function remove
{
    param(
    $name)

    $name = Read-Host "Which folder would you like to delete?"
    Write-Host "Folder" $name "is now deleted"
    Remove-Item $name
}

function rename
{

    param(
     $OldName)
     ($NewName) 
    
    $OldName = Read-host "Which folder would you like to rename?"
    $NewName = Read-host "What would you like the new name to be?"
    Rename-Item $OldFolderName -NewName $NewName
    Write-Host "The folder" $OldFolderName "has now been rename " $NewName
}

function Show-Menu
{
    param(
        [string]$Title = 'Technical Menu'
    )
    cls
    Write-Host "========== $Title =========="
    Write-Host "1. Rename a Directory"
    Write-Host "2. Create a New Directory"
    Write-Host "3. Delete a Directory"
    Write-Host "4. Press 'Q or q' to quit"
}



function Directory
{
    param(
        [string]$Title = 'Directory'
    )
    cls
    Write-Host "========== $Title =========="
    Write-Host "1. Documents"
    Write-Host "2. Downloads"
    Write-Host "3. Photos"
    Write-Host "4. Press 'Q or q' to quit"
}


function Documents
{
    param(
        [string]$Title = 'Documents'
    )
    cls
    Write-Host "========== $Documents =========="
    get-childitem -Path C:\Users\BFG83\Documents
    
    
}

function Downloads
{
    param(
        [string]$Title = 'Downloads'
    )
    cls
    Write-Host "========== $Downloads =========="
    get-childitem -Path C:\Users\BFG83\Downloads
    
    
}


function Pictures
{
    param(
        [string]$Title = 'Pictures'
    )
    cls
    Write-Host "========== $Pictures =========="
    get-childitem -Path C:\Users\BFG83\Pictures
    
    
}


do
 {
     Show-Menu
     $condition = $flase
     $selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($selection)
     {
         '1' {

             rename
         } '2' {

             create
         } '3' {

            remove
         }
     }
     pause
 }
 until ($selection -eq 'q')


 do
 {
     Directory
     $condition = $flase
     $selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($selection)
     {
         '1' {

             Documents
         } '2' {

             Downloads
         } '3' {

            Pictures
         }
     }
     pause
 }
 until ($selection -eq 'q')
```

I tried using Func Directory inside the Rename,create and Delete functions.

Comment: Why would you use parameters if in your functions you immediately overwrite them by using `Read-Host` ? And you have a typo: `$condition = $flase` --> `$condition = $false` (although you never use that variable..)

Answer (score 1):

U could separate the user interaction (read-host write-host) and create one function with three Parameters:

```
Function folderOperation([String]$dir, [String]$operation, [String]$folderName){

 $path=“C:\Users\BFG83“\$dir\$folderName“
   switch ($operation)
     {
         'Create' {
            New-Item $path -ItemType "directory"
         } 'remove' {
            Remove-item $path
         } 'rename' {
            $newName= read-host “Enter new name“
            Rename-Item $path -NewName $NewName
         }
     }


}

$dir=read-host “Enter dir“
$operation=read-host “Enter operation“
$folderName=read-host “enter folder“


folderOperation $dir $operation $folderName
```

Good idea of looping the user input till q is entered. Same u could do to prevent wrong input and wrap that up in one function „enterSomething“. To automate your choises (create, remove, rename and downloads, documents and pictures here is a useful article on „Read-Host and the ChoiceDescription class“
https://4sysops.com/archives/read-host-and-the-choicedescription-class-prompt-for-user-input-in-powershell/