# Technical menu to rename create and delete a folder

Tags: powershell

I created this Technical menu after asking a previous question for help Which is from here ([How to add a Function inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74772310/how-to-add-a-function-inside-a-function/74777299#74777299)). Im just asking today if anyone can think of making this more efficient and smaller.

```
cls
function rename
{     

write-host "------------------------------------ 

Where Do You Want To Rename a Folder?:

A. Documents
B. Pictures
C. Downloads
"

$choice = read-host "Please Choose A Directory Location" 

switch($choice)

{
"A" {cd ~/Documents;$valid = $true}
"B" {cd ~/Pictures;$valid = $true}
"C" {cd ~/Downloads;$valid = $true}
default {"
";$valid = $false}
}

while ($valid -eq $false)
{ if ($valid -eq $true){Break}
}

ls 
$name = read-host "
What Folder Do You Want To Rename"

$newname = read-host "Enter The New Folder Name" 

Rename-Item $name -NewName $newname

write-host "------------------------------------"  
write-host "Refreshed Directory: ------------------------------------"
ls
write-host "------------------------------------"
write-host " $name Has Been Renamed To $newname"}


function remove
{     
write-host "
------------------------------------ 
What Directory Do You Want To Delete A Folder?: 

A. Documents
B. Pictures
C. Downloads
"
$choice = read-host "Please Choose A Directory Location"  
switch($choice)
{

"A" {cd ~/Documents;$valid = $true}
"B" {cd ~/Pictures;$valid = $true}
"C" {cd ~/Downloads;$valid = $true}
default {"
";$valid = $false}
}

while ($valid -eq $false){ 

if ($valid -eq $true){Break}
}

ls 

$name = read-host "What Folder Do You Want To Delete"


Remove-Item $name 
write-host "------------------------------------" 
write-host "Refreshed Directory: ------------------------------------"
ls
write-host "------------------------------------"
write-host " $name Has Been Deleted"}



function create
{     
write-host "------------------------------------ 
Where Do You Want To Rename A New Folder?:

A. Documents
B. Pictures
C. Downloads"

$choice = read-host "Please Choose A Directory Location"  

switch($choice)
{
"A" {cd ~/Documents;$valid = $true}
"B" {cd ~/Pictures;$valid = $true}
"C" {cd ~/Downloads;$valid = $true}
default {"
";$valid = $false}
}
while ($valid -eq $false){
if ($valid -eq $true){Break}
}
ls 


$name = read-host "
What Is The Name Of The Folder You Want to create"  


New-Item $name 

write-host "------------------------------------" 
write-host "Refreshed Directory: ------------------------------------"

ls

write-host "------------------------------------"
write-host " $name Has Been Created!"
}

function Show-Menu
{    

    param(       
        [string]$Title = 'Directory Technical Menu' 
    )   
    cls    
    Write-Host "========== $Title =========="
    Write-Host "1. Rename a Directory"   
    Write-Host "2. Create a New Directory"   
    Write-Host "3. Delete a Directory"    
    Write-Host "4. Press 'Q or q' to quit"
}

do 
 {     
    Show-Menu     
    $condition = $flase     
    $selection = Read-Host "Please Choose an Option"     
    switch ($selection)     
    {         
        '1' {             
                rename         
       } '2' {             
                create         
       } '3' {           
                remove         
       }     
    }    
 pause 
} 
until ($selection -eq 'q')
```

The code works perfectly to what i need it to do, was just trying to find a way to make it smaller and more efficient

Comment: If you have taken the answer in your previous question, then why didn't you accept that answer? Please read the [tour] to see how you do that.

Comment: For making working code more efficient, [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask.